# If $T$ is linear and maps $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $T(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(a_1+a_2,a_3)$ is $N(T)=\{(a_1,a_1,0)\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the basis. Please don't give me the basis because it's for a graded assignment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But what is the vector of the basis for the kernel? You have to show one vector since you're saying that its dimension is one. OK. it's true that any other non zero multiple is again a basis, but I believe that it is missing a minus sign.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm thinking....

Comment: Okay. So R(T)= x,y plane right? Or no?... I'm trying to figure out why I'm missing a sign.

Comment: You have to solve $a_1+a_2=0$ and $a_3=0$.

Comment: Whoops. A minus sign... I was over thinking your post.

Comment: +1 for "don't give me the basis because it's for a graded assignment". Asking for an explanation rather than solution is commendable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $T:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2,$ then $$N(T)=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:T(x,y,z)=(0,0)\}.$$ Using the specific definition of $T$, we have $$N(T)=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:(x+y,z)=(0,0)\},$$ which is the same as $$N(T)=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3:x+y=0,z=0\}.$$ Do you see why this is different from what you have?

Comment: Thank you guys!! I understand. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Forest for the trees!

Comment: I've had those days.... Glad to help.

Comment: @court, the idea is simple. Just be careful with the math.

Comment: Will do. Thank you guys again.